# Intent data passed from branch.io links on facebook don't let deep linking

Tags: facebook, android-intent, xamarin.forms, branch.io

I'm working with Xamarin forms and Branch Xamarin SDK v2.1
When I open a non facebook shared branch link my activity receive this as Intent DataString:
    cirql://open?link_click_id=256421691057450068

and deep linking works just fine but with a facebook shared link my DataString is:
    cirql://open?link_click_id=link-256421691057450068&target_url=https%3A%2F%2Fbnc.lt%2FSLEn%2FDfVaEjqR8s

Adding unnecessary data and in my
    InitSessionComplete (Dictionary data) data parameter doesn't brings any links data but the default "is_first_session" and "clicked_branch_link"

Any clue how to fix that?

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: sorry you're running into issues with this! To sort out what is going on here, we may need to take a look at your APK and Branch app configuration directly. Would you mind [submitting a support ticket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079794/intent-data-passed-from-branch-io-links-on-facebook-dont-let-deep-linking), and then we can put an answer here when more is known?

Comment: Hi @AlexBauer where can I send my report? whould I have directly support right now?

Comment: Ahhhh, so sorry! Wrong link paste. The support URL is here: http://support.branch.io